# MAUI How to set Entry closing button color?

Tags: maui

I would like to use an **Entry** in my **MAUI** application.
The MAUI Entry has a close button, but in my application this is displayed in white on a white background, so it is not visible. The font color is set to black.  The style is standard (at least for testing purposes). I have not redesigned the entry. Nevertheless, I do not see the close button (cross).

**How can I give the close button a color** (or background color)**?**

```
<Entry ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
       BackgroundColor="White"
       TextColor="Black" />
```

Comment: You asked 2 questions: "without closing Button" or "give the close button a color" ?

Comment: Thank you, I have concretised the title.

Comment: You said The MAUI Entry has a close button, can you show relevant code and add it to your post to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @FrankMehlhop You need create a .NET 8 Mui project and then you can use the `TextColor` value to set the `ClearButton` color on the Entry, see this merged one:[Use the TextColor value to set the ClearButton color on the Entry #13475](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13475)

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT As you see at my code example I've set the TextColor to black. I'm using .NET8. And the problem appears only on Windows (not on Android, not on iOS. The examples on your link are Android and iOS.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop I've tested it before, and it doesn't work on Windows. I'll see if we can figure it out.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop This potential issue only exists on Windows, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19152. But on my side, the close is visible(light gray) even it's in a white background. [see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWWpV.png).